# Remove HTML tags in Freemarker Template

Tags: java, html, freemarker

I've got a freemarker template that displays the same string in a context where HTML is allowed as well as a context where it is not.

Is there a built-in in Freemarker that allows me to entirely remove HTML tags from a string?

The following template (assuming there was a built-in `remove_html`)

```xml
<#ftl output_format="HTML"/>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>${page_title?remove_html}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>${page_title?no_esc}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the model `Collections.singletonMap("page_title", "A <strong>Strong</strong> Argument")` should lead to

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A Strong Argument</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>A <strong>Strong</strong> Argument</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Using the built-in `esc` would give me `<title>A &lt;strong&gt;Strong&lt;/strong&gt; Argument</title>` instead, which is *not* what I am looking for.

Is there something like `remove_html` or do I need to provide my own? (Using [OWASP's java-html-sanitizer](https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer), for instance.)

Comment: I would not fix things like this in the presentation layer, but in the business layer. There you could create a title based on the primary header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the Freemarker built-in string replace function with the "r" flag to enable regular expressions.

Here's a simple regexp that does the trick:

```
${page_title?replace('<[^>]+>','','r')}
```

Note that if you use backslashes within the regular expression they must be escaped, as follows (contrived example that removes whitespace):

```
${page_title?replace('\\s+','','r')}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything built in as of 2.3.28, so yes, you have to create your own.