# display quotation marks within a variable freemarker - netsuite advanced pdf

Tags: netsuite, freemarker, quotation-marks

I'm trying to show results in the PDF from the netsuite database, however some results have quotation marks, so the results are incomplete, try adding "? Html" at the end of each variable, but do not It affects the column that I want.
I hope and you can help me, greetings!

Netsuite Advanced PDF template - Freemarker

```
<table cellmargin="5"><#list results as result><tr>
    <td style="width: 150px;">
      <#if result.custitem_gg_item_image?length != 0><img src="https://----com${result.custitem_gg_item_image}" style="width: 125px; height: 125px;"/><#else><img src="https:/---.com" style="width: 125px; height: 125px;"/></#if>
        </td>
    <td><strong style="font-size: 12pt"><u><span>${result.itemid?html}</span></u></strong><br/><br/><strong style="font-size: 10pt"><span>${result.displayname?html}</span></strong><br/><br/>
      <#if result.purchasedescription?length != 0><span>${result.purchasedescription?html}</span><#else><span>${result.salesdescription?html}</span></#if></td>
    </tr>
    </#list>
  </table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just having a quotation mark in the field values shouldn't cause any issues. Do you also have html in the sales and purchase descriptions? Normally you should not do that -- leave the html for the storedetaileddescription field.

If your issue is actually html in the descriptions then see this answer: [Remove HTML tags in Freemarker Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784172/remove-html-tags-in-freemarker-template)