# How do I get the word count of a string that includes HTML?

Tags: freemarker

I have a FreeMarker template that renders a blog post. I want to get the word count of the blog post so that I can push it to [Google Tag Manager](https://tagmanager.google.com) for analytics. The caveat here is that the word count cannot include the HTML characters.

I've combined the [`word_list`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html?source=post_page---------------------------#ref_builtin_word_list) and [`size`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html?source=post_page---------------------------#ref_builtin_size) built-ins which gets me close.

```
[#assign blogPost = "<h1>The Chihuahua</h1><p>The chihuahua ran across the road. Everyone thought it was a bad idea.</p><p>But he made it safely across.</p>"]

${blogPost?word_list?size}
```

However, I need to strip out the HTML before I count the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Remove HTML tags in Freemarker Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784172/remove-html-tags-in-freemarker-template?answertab=votes#tab-top) provides the final missing piece. Append the [`replace`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_replace) built-in with the "r" flag before the `word_list` and `size` built-ins:

```
${blogPost?replace("<[^>]+>", "", "r")?word_list?size}
```